# Converting string to datetime is returning the min value

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am using Visual Studio and I want to convert the string I have in my textbox into the `DateTime` format. I am using the function `Convert.ToDateTime()` but the value that is returned is the min value (`0/0/0001 00:00:00`).

What is the problem?

The code where I retrieve the string from my textbox.

```
//pass startdate end date to studentResult.aspx
Session["startdate"] = txtStartDate.Text.ToString();
Session["enddate"] = txtEndDate.Text.ToString();
```

The code where I convert the string to datetime format.

```
string startdate = (string)(Session["startdate"]);
string enddate = (string)(Session["enddate"]);
DateTime one = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
DateTime two = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);
```

Comment: What is the value of your `textbox` value?

Comment: Cannot you share the code?

Comment: Are you trying to convert the textbox itself to a DateTime or its text property? ie `Convert.ToDateTime(myTextBox)` or `Convert.ToDateTime(myTextBox.Text)`

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` method returns `DateTime.MinValue` if the parameter is `null`. Are you sure you using it like `Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)` ?

Comment: Soner Gonul - startdate is "07/08/2013" and enddate is "07/09/2013"

Squid - I'm trying to convert the string i got from my textbox and passed through session.

Comment: @山本一樹 `Startdate` and `enddate`? What are these? Which one is the value of your `TextBox`? **Put a breakpoints and check what are the values of `startdate` and `enddate`**.

Comment: values of textbox aren't stored in session unless you put them there explicitly.  try using Request["startdate"] instead of Session.

Comment: Soner Gonul - I've already posted the value that the breakpoints gave me when I ran the application. It is "07/08/2013" and "07/09/2013" respectively.

BlackICE - So i call Request["startdate"]? How about the posting of the string value through session? Do I still need to do it?

Comment: @山本一樹 If your `Startdate` value was really `"07/08/2013"`, **it wouldn't give any error**. Look at this [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/mmsqhZ). It is perfectly fine..

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but does the format matter? Cause my month is at the front followed by day and then year. Is it supposed to be day,followed by month then year?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540542/converting-string-to-datetime-is-returning-the-min-value#comment25511004_17540542), [`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx) method returns [`DateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) if the parameter is `null`.

```
Return Value
Type: System.DateTime
The date and time equivalent of the value of value, or the date and time equivalent of DateTime.MinValue if value is null.
```

Probably your parameter is `null` but since you didn't gave us more details, we can't know what the exact problem is.

As a comman mistake, make sure that you are passing as a parameter `.Text` property of your `TextBox`, not itself. See Squid's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540542/converting-string-to-datetime-is-returning-the-min-value#comment25510968_17540542).

Answer (score 0):

use try parse, it'll return false if any conversion error occurs

```
Datetime @dateTime;

if(DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out @dateTime)) {
    return @dateTime;
}
```